# Write every nth line from list to new row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a list that contains numbers like this:

```
[20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7]
```

and i want to write the list to a csv file that should look like this:

```
20.5, 21.7
23.0, 23.6
24.0, 24.7
```

so every second line in my list should be written to the next row in the csv file.

right now my script just looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('result.csv','w') as f:
    for line in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

how can i write only every nth line as a new line and every nth line as new row?

Comment: import [numpy](https://numpy.org/), [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), [`savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @alex This can be solved without requiring a huge dependency like numpy…

Comment: i tried to count the lines and pass every 2nth line to the next row but somehow it didn't work

Comment: If you are only after a simple CSV, and your input sizes are relatively small, probably the fastest approach is to use `csv` and `itertools`.

Comment: @deceze sure, I just use it everywhere all the time, so that's the first thing that poped in my mind

Comment: @norok2 This can be done by pure python without using any libraries.

Comment: @SharimIqbal sure, just that the code is so much more robust / cleaner using a proper library.

Comment: @norok2 Ya, But for a new programmer using pure python is best.

Comment: I'd argue using proper tools, but OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the space after the comma:

```
import csv

data = [20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7]

with open('result.csv','w') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2))
```

Otherwise:

```
with open('result.csv','w') as file:
    file.writelines(
        ", ".join(map(str, data[i:i + 2])) + "\n" for i in range(0, len(data), 2)
    )
```

Comment: I think this answer could be largely improved by rewriting the code with functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way without using any libraries.

```py
import csv
my_list = [20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7]
nth_line = 2 #--> You can give other values too.
with open('result.csv','w') as f:
    for line in range(len(my_list)):
        f.write(str(my_list[line]))
        if (line+1) % nth_line == 0:
            f.write('\n')
        else:
            f.write(', ')
```

Comment: Where do you use `csv`?

Comment: @norok2 This is in the questioner's post.

Comment: You `import csv` and never use it. If you omit the first line, the rest of the code works likewise.

Comment: @norok2 Because, this is in the questioner's post.

Comment: One more reason to fix it. It was not needed there, it is not needed here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243815/discussion-between-sharim-iqbal-and-norok2).

Comment: @norok2 I know removing the first line of the code is best, I write this because this is in the questionnaire post.

Comment: @00000cs000000 I think you can use this code now, I edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

By re-shaping the list, then writing all at once:

```py
import csv

data = [20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7]
data = [data[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(data), 2)]

with open("results.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

---

This will word for odd lengths as well:

```
# len = 7
data = [20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7, 0]
```

`results.csv`

```
20.5,21.7
23.0,23.6
24.0,24.7
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution that works in all cases:

```
from math import *

my_list = [20.5, 21.7, 23.0, 23.6, 24.0, 24.7]

values_per_line = 2

with open('result.csv','w') as f:
    i = 0
    number_of_lines = ceil(len(my_list)/values_per_line)
    for line in range(number_of_lines):
        for value in range(values_per_line):
            if i < len(my_list)-1:
                if value == (values_per_line - 1):
                    f.write("%s" % my_list[i])
                else:
                    f.write("%s, " % my_list[i])
            elif i == len(my_list)-1:
                f.write("%s" % my_list[i])
            i = i + 1

        if line != number_of_lines-1:
            f.write("\n")
```

You can change the values_per_line to whatever you need.